# MariaDB 10.3 Fast, 10.5 Slow

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB 10.3 Galera cluster with a DB that I'm migrating to newer hardware and upgrading to 10.5. When I `mysqldump` the database from the old server and import it into the new, any `JOIN` is god-awful slow. Here's an example query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM claim_notes
         INNER JOIN claims
                 ON claim_notes.claim_id = claims.id
         INNER JOIN users
                 ON claim_notes.user_id = users.id
 WHERE claim_notes.email_queue = 1
```

This runs in 0.7 seconds on the old cluster, and 3 minutes and 51 seconds on the new cluster. Yes, it's a stupid query, but it demonstrates the point.

Given that the database schema (including all indexes) along with the entire data set is identical across both setups, I can rule out poorly-optimized queries, or something like the optimizer treating them differently because of different data sets.

However, the optimizer does seem to treat them very differently, according to `EXPLAIN`. Old setup:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys                                        | key         | key_len | ref                                   | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | claim_notes | ref    | claim_id,email_queue,user_id,claim_type_user_dtstamp | email_queue | 1       | const                                 |    3 |       |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | users       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                              | PRIMARY     | 4       | guido_commercial.claim_notes.user_id  |    1 |       |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | claims      | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                              | PRIMARY     | 4       | guido_commercial.claim_notes.claim_id |    1 |       |
+------+-------------+-------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

New setup:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys                                        | key         | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                              |
+------+-------------+-------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | claims      | ALL  | PRIMARY                                              | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  | 1    |                                    |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | users       | ALL  | PRIMARY                                              | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  | 1    | Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | claim_notes | ref  | claim_id,email_queue,user_id,claim_type_user_dtstamp | email_queue | 1       | const | 5    | Using where                        |
+------+-------------+-------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

All of the values being compared (like `claim_notes.claim_id`, `claims.id`, etc.) are all indexed (again, same schema across both). So the fact that `EXPLAIN` shows no key usage for 2 of the 3 steps is strange.

This seems to be *key* (pun intended). It sounds like a configuration issue.. some change that occurred between 10.1 and 10.5 that changed the way indexes are utilized. But after hours of Googling and trial-and-error, I'm not able to find anything to resolve the issue (I did find this one (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25707) that looked promising, but I tried setting `eq_range_index_dive_limit` to 0 and no change).

**UPDATES:**

- Old Version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
- New Version: 10.5.18-MariaDB-0+deb11u1-log

Ooops.. I originally posted the old as 10.1, so I fixed that.

```
CREATE TABLE `claims` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=173985 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `claim_notes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `claim_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email_queue` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `claim_id` (`claim_id`),
  KEY `email_queue` (`email_queue`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26559123 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `active` (`active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=576 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

These tables actually have quite a few more columns, but I removed them for brevity since they are completely unrelated to the query in questions.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show output of `show create table ...;` for all three tables?

Comment: Also `select version();` (old and new)

Comment: @ysth I've updated the question with the requested information. Thanks!

Comment: Does `select straight_join * ...` speed it up or affect the explain?  Asking mostly to know if there's just something systemic making the new system slower

Comment: First try [analyze table](https://mariadb.org/mariadb-30x-faster/). Appending `claim_id` and `user_id` to the `email_queue` index will probably help too.

Comment: @ysth Yes, adding `straight_join` makes it perform just as it did on the old server.

Comment: @danblack Running `ANALYZE TABLE` as the linked article recommended, on each table, helped tremendously. The query is now down to just over 1 second. A bit slower than on the old server (which is a different mystery, it seems, as the old server is.. well.. older). But this seems to have solved the majority of the issue. I assumed that running `mysqldump` and importing the result would handle everything for me as far as transferring the database.

Comment: @danblack I'd appreciate if you'd add your comment, with any relevant details, as an answer so I could mark it as the accepted answer since it is what solved my issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you upgrade any software, some things may work a little different. MariaDB as a database adds various optimizer types.

Ultimately the query plan may have been lucky in the earlier version based on statistics. When getting a slow query, relook at the [indexing basics](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots#indexing) for making sure that its easy for MariaDB to make good decisions.

As a strict `where` condition is on the `email_queue` is there, and assuming its highly selective, appending to the index this would use by putting `claim_id`,`user_id`, gives the query the information it needs to join to the other `claim` and `user` tables quickly. Remember the principles that a query uses a single index per table in a query. Use multiple column indexes to help out queries as much as possible.

The statistics, a summary information about a table can get out of data. Using [ANALYZE TABLE](https://mariadb.org/mariadb-30x-faster/) on any tables of the query will help the optimizer have a accurate representation of the table in question.

Another oddity in the presented question is in the `claim_notes` is `id` is a good primary key. If `claim_id`, `user_id` in combination is unique, maybe that is a better primary key.

With indexing remember that the primary key is invisibly there after the end of all the secondary indexes.